# Selecting the last set of records in SQL Server that match certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got 10 records that match the criteria I'm searching for.  The problem is there are two sets of 10 records, one at 1pm and one at 3pm.  I only want the sets at 3pm.  Here's part of my SQL:

```
    select shp_rev.ShpNum, shp_rev.RevTime
      from shp_rev
     where shp_rev.RevDate  = '10/1/2015'
       and shp_rev.ValAfter = 'O'
       and shp_rev.ShpNum   = 732809
```

(I've added the shp_rev.ShpNum to the where just to narrow down the data to a dataset that has this problem.  Normally I wouldn't have that in the where.  And there are other fields that would be included with this select.)

This produces:

```
    732809 13:14:45
    732809 13:14:45
    ...
    732809 15:23:33
    732809 15:23:33
    ...
```

I only want the records at 15:23:33. I know one way I can do it is to concatenate all of the fields I want into one string with ShpNum and RevTime at the beginning then using MAX() to get just the 3pm records like this:

```
    select max(cast(shp_rev.ShpNum as varchar) + '~' + shp_rev.RevTime)
      from shp_rev
     where shp_rev.RevDate  = '10/1/2015'
       and shp_rev.ValAfter = 'O'
       and shp_rev.ShpNum   = 732809
     order by max(cast(shp_rev.ShpNum as varchar) + '~' + shp_rev.RevTime)
```

But then I have to parse back that string to get everything.  It seems there must be a better way.  I've tried using MAX() on ShpNum and RevTime separately but that doesn't work.  Any thoughts?  Oh, I'm working in SQL Server 2012.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select s.*
from (select shp_rev.ShpNum, shp_rev.RevTime,
             dense_rank() over (partition by revdate, valafter, shipnum order by revtime desc) as seqnum
      from shp_rev
      where shp_rev.RevDate  = '2015-10-01' and
            shp_rev.ValAfter = 'O' and
            shp_rev.ShpNum   = 732809
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes that the time stamps are all exactly the same.